# Model-View-Controller with UIViewController and Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

Am I correct in understanding, that at the high-level, when operating with a `.xib` or `.storyboard`, the model-view-controller paradigm is structured so that the `.xib` or `.storyboard` is the `view`, which the `.h` of the `UIViewController` file is the `model` and the `.m` is the `controller`? Is this just a very basic way of understanding the connection with a model-view-controller structured program, or am I getting this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The View can be contained by the .xib or a concrete scene in a .storyboard (which are not necessarily part of the MVC), the Controller is usually the UIViewController or any subclass of it that usually we define, the Model is another class that you should create. The Model should not communicate with the View. The Controller takes care of everything. For example when there is a change in the Model, the Controller changes the View, and when the user interact with the View, the Controller can change the model. Neither the View nor the Model communicate directly with the Controller.

For more, check this link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html

Answer (score 0):

A `xib` or `storyboard` is a container from which objects can be loaded. Those files are not themselves a part of the "MVC" pattern. The objects loaded from those files are usually `UIView` subclasses (part of the "view" layer) and `UIViewController` subclasses (part of the "controller" layer).